# Microsoft Moles Generic Method with output parameter

Tags: c#, delegates, moles

Hi I am trying to mole out this function from a public SettingsManager class

```
public static bool GetSetting<T>(Application application, int instanceId, out T Setting)     where T : ICacheSetting, new()
```

I've gotten this far

```
MSettingsManager.GetSettingApplicationInt32TOut<ApplicationSettings>()
```

but the parameters for this are asking for a `OutFunc mole:void` and I'm lost as to what to put in there.  Any help would be greatly appreciated